# How to deploy storm-core topology with apache kafka integration for first time?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I would like to get help for initial setup with apache storm and kafka setup.

I was able to submit topology to the storm cluster but getting below error in *storm ui*.

```
Unable to get offset lags for kafka. Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: zk-node '/kafka-cluster-1/brokers/topics/myfirsttopic/aadb3eb4-2224-4c18-b8ad-6959a1c9f607' dose not exists. at org.apache.storm.kafka.monitor.KafkaOffsetLagUtil.getOldConsumerOffsetsFromZk(KafkaOffsetLagUtil.java:387) at org.apache.storm.kafka.monitor.KafkaOffsetLagUtil.getOffsetLags(KafkaOffsetLagUtil.java:268) at org.apache.storm.kafka.monitor.KafkaOffsetLagUtil.main(KafkaOffsetLagUtil.java:124)
```

My code snippet is below.

```
// Kafka consumer client depends on Zookeeper when finding kafka nodes.
// Zookeeper Host List
String zkConnString = "localhost:2181";
String brokerZkPath = "/kafka-cluster-1/brokers";
String zkRoot       = "/kafka-cluster-1/brokers/topics";
String topicName    = "myfirsttopic";

/* ****************************************************************** */
/* Topology configuration variable                                    */
/* ****************************************************************** */
/* the number of tasks that should be assigned to execute this bolt   */
Integer boltParalismHint  = 1;
Integer spoutParalismHint = 1;

/* ****************************************************************** */
/* Build kafka consumer spout                                         */
/* ****************************************************************** */
// Build zookeeper instance
BrokerHosts hosts = new ZkHosts( zkConnString, brokerZkPath );

// Build configuration instance for Spout
SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig( hosts, topicName, zkRoot + "/" + topicName , UUID.randomUUID().toString() );

spoutConfig.ignoreZkOffsets = true;

// Build Multischeme instance
spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme( new StringScheme() );

// Build Kafka spout
KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig);
```

I have referenced the  [document](http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.2.1/storm-kafka.html) and set *ignoreZkOffsets* to **true**.

> If you want to force the spout to ignore any consumer state
>   information stored in ZooKeeper, then you should set the parameter
>   KafkaConfig.ignoreZkOffsets to true

**However** , from the log , kafka spout is seems to be reading the offset from Zookeeper.

Since its an intial setup , how can I stop storm reading offsets from Zookeeper ?

I use below versions.

- apache storm 1.2.1
- apache kafka kafka_2.12-1.1.0

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am facing the same problem. @Yu Watanabe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not do anything special but in below condition , the error seems to not appear in *storm ui* .

1. Create topic in *Kafka*
2. Make sure that the *brokerZkPath* exists in *Zookeeper*  (Path to *brokers* directory. In my case */kafka-cluster-1/brokers*)
3. Make sure that the *zkRootPath* exists in *Zookeeper* (Path to *topics* directory. In my case */kafka-cluster-1/brokers/topics*)
4. Submit topology to storm